# Subtract days from a date in a text field

Tags: regex, r, lubridate

I have some text that looks like this:

```
"Word1 word2 word3 word4 12/31/1980 word word words"  
"Word1 word2 word3 11/2/90 word word words 10/2/1991."   
"Word1 8/1/2003 word2 word3 word4 11/8/1990 word word words October 4, 1997 words."
```

I want to replace the current dates with the days between the dates in the text and another date.

So for example in this case:

```
"Word1 word2 word3 word4 1000 word word words"  
"Word1 word2 word3 2000 word word words 2365."  
"Word1 4000 word2 word3 word4 4005 word word words 5000 words."
```

(I made up the replacement numbers by the way.)

I had some trouble with mdy() getting the year correct. So far my solution has been a two step process of extracting and formatting the date, and then going through and replacing it in the text field.

```
# extract and format 2 digit year dates

    re <- ".*\\s+(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2})\\D.*" 
    path$path_date_magic_2year <- mdy(with(path, ifelse(grepl(re,   path_notes),sub(re,'\\1',path_notes),'')))

# replace the date in the text with the extracted and formatted date 
    for (i in 1:length(path$path_date_magic_2year)){
      if (!is.na(path$path_date_magic_2year[i])) {
        path$path_date_magic_2year_test[i] <- sub('\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2}',              path$path_date_magic_2year[i] , path$path_notes[i])
  }
}
```

(After I do the 2 digit year  dates, then I do the 4 digit year dates and then the month written out dates. mdy() theoretically handles all of that, but not all of them were correct when I did that initially while being almost perfect when separated.)

So there's that.

When there's just one date in the text field, the current method works.

So my remaining issue is how to handle the case when there is more than one date in the text. I have anywhere from 1 to 6 dates in the free text field.

What I would like to do is fix it all in one step, regardless of the number of dates in the text field, using gsub, for a greedy substitution.  I haven't found a way to make that work, yet, though.

Any ideas how I could make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the vector `txt` contains your text and `myDate` is the minuend:

```
myDate <- Sys.Date() # for example
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english") # if needed
regex <- paste0("\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2,4}", "|((", paste(month.name, collapse = "|"), ") \\d{1,2}, \\d{2,4})")
days <- sapply(lapply(matches <- regmatches(txt, gregexpr(regex, txt)), function(x) if (length(x)) as.Date(x, lubridate::guess_formats(x, "mdy"))) , function(date) as.numeric(myDate - date))
for (x in seq_along(txt)) 
  for (y in seq_along(days[[x]])) 
    txt[x] <- sub(matches[[x]][y], days[[x]][y], txt[x], fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "Word1 word2 word3 word4 12518 word word words"                
# [2] "Word1 word2 word3 8925 word word words 8591."                 
# [3] "Word1 4270 word2 word3 word4 8919 word word words 6397 words."
```

Comment: Thanks!! That totally worked, once I tracked down the one field with a three digit year :)